# How to use ImportXML XPath concat within Google Docs?

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets

I am trying to add a character (any) to my XML import in Google Spreadsheet

```
=importxml($B$7,C10)

$B$7 = website: www.google.com
C10 = query: //*[contains(@id,'#')]/tr[2]/td[2]/text()
```

Actual results:

```
11-045067-135
11-045678-139
11-045117-138
11-045987-142
...
```

How could I use the formula, concatenation to generate the following result:

```
"a-" + "11-045067-135" = a-11-045067-135

a-11-045067-135
a-11-045678-139
a-11-045117-138
a-11-045987-142
a-...
```

Comment: Please always make sure to post reproducible code. For Spreadsheet questions, always (additionally to every important part in the question!) better create a public spreadsheet to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the result of your XPath, but this is not necessary as the problem cannot be solved using XPath 1.0 (the only supported by Spreadsheets) anyway. Use `ARRAYFORMULA` to concatenate the prefix to every result. `&` concatenates two strings.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA("a-" & IMPORTXML("http://www.google.com", "//@id"))
```

Just wrap this against your own `IMPORTXML` call.

Comment: I've been struggling to pre-pend my imported data using `JOIN`, `CONCAT`, and `CONCATENATE`, but it's not the right function for my needs. This helped me out to prepend my extracted data from xPath's `@href` syntax with a base url like `http://domain.com/`